# Completion time in DX:HR

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm 15 hours into the game and I'm playing quite thoroughly.

- Approximately how many hours should a thorough player get out of the game?
- If you focus on only the main missions, how quickly could it be done?

Comment: What mission are you on currently, that'll give me a good indication of how much is left for you specifically.

Comment: I'm in China trying to escape some hotel so I can break into some medial company. Does that clarify?

Comment: then you are fairly close to the end, probably 70% done

Comment: @yx, that's untrue, trying to break into Tai Yong is immediately after you leave detroit for the first time, so I'd say he's about 40% done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally am one of those players who tries to do EVERYTHING, explore everything, find everything etc, and it took me around 40ish hours on "Give me Deus Ex". Including restarts.

I have no idea how short it can be completed, but I've heard around 10 hours? Don't quote me on that though.

Answer (score 1):

Current numbers at [How Long To Beat](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamebreakdown.php?gameid=1857) put it at ~18 hours to complete the main storyline, and ~35-40 for completionists that want to do *everything*, with most players falling somewhere in between.

Expect those numbers to become more precise (and probably higher, given the way HLTB works) as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

I explored everything, tried to do all the quest I could find without a guide, and on deus ex difficulty, took me ~26 hours.  I ended up missing two major side quests, but had enough praxis points to fill almost every aug because of my obsession with hacking everything I come across.